# Interview test about polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I was asked in a job interview, if I can implement a simple solution for the following problem :

- Create a class that manages different databases. this class has basically 3 methods: `Open()`, `Close()`, `Dataset GetDataSet( .. )`
- The `Open()` and `Close()` are identical for all DB types.
- The method `Dataset GetDataSet()` behaves differently for each type of server
- I need to implement this without using *"IF"* sentence.
- The funtion calling these methods is not exposed to the internal functionality.

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DBManager dbm = new DBManager();
    dbm.getDataSet();
}
```

and this :

```
public Dataset getDataSet()
{
    OpenConn();
    // get dataset

    // sdb = new SQL / new Oracle <-- I AM NOT ALLOWED TO USE "IF" HERE

    // that's it 
    CloseConn();

    return sdb;
}
```

Comment: You have omitted to ask a question.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: are you allowed to inherit ? means : SqlDateSet : DataSet  ? so getDataSet() would be Abstract ?:) or you could use Switch instead of if XD. or create 3 data sets in a list and call getdataset(index) XD  ok ok Forget the last two Solutions ^^

Comment: so what was the answer after the job interview (or is this "homework"`)?

Comment: I am allowed to use any means in OOP i choose (Inheritance, interface, abstraction.. etc ) except to use the "IF" sentence..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with an abstract base class and just override the method which differs from the base implementation (classic polymorphism):

```
abstract class BaseDbManager {
    public void OpenConn() {
        //implementation goes here
    }
    public void CloseCon() {
        //implementation goes here
    }
    public abstract DataSet GetDataSet(...);
}
```

And then use inherited classes for each DB type:

```
class OracleDbManager : BaseDbManager {
    public override DataSet GetDataSet(...) {
        //implementation goes here
    }
}

class MsSqlDbManager : BaseDbManager {
    public override DataSet GetDataSet(...) {
        //implementation goes here
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: This is fine, but when i want to create a new object , how do I know which object to create without using the "IF" ?

Comment: Ah ok, I see the problem. Then it would be useful, where the information, what database is used, would be helpful. Instead of using an abstract base class, you could give that info to the constructor of your class then, or use a factory to create the internal object.